# Celery Result type for ElasticSearch

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch, celery

I'm exploring celery for my work currently and I'm trying to set-up Elasticsearch backend. Is there any way to send resulting value as a dictionary/JSON, not as a text? Therefore, results in Elasticsearch will be shown correctly and nested type could be used?

[image]

Automatic mapping created by celery

```
{
  "celery" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "backend" : {
        "properties" : {
          "@timestamp" : {
            "type" : "date"
          },
          "result" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried to create my own mapping with nested field, but it has resulted in a `elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'mapper_parsing_exception', 'object mapping for [result] tried to parse field [result] as object, but found a concrete value')`

UPDATE

Result is already encoded in JSON and inside Elasticsearch wrapper JSON string is saved inside a dictionary. Adding `json.loads(result)` as a quick-fix actually helps.

After the quick-fix new mapping has appeared:

```
{
  "celery" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "backend" : {
        "properties" : {
          "@timestamp" : {
            "type" : "date"
          },
          "result" : {
            "properties" : {
              "date_done" : {
                "type" : "date"
              },
              "result" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "status" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "fields" : {
                  "keyword" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
                    "ignore_above" : 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "task_id" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "fields" : {
                  "keyword" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
                    "ignore_above" : 256
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Updated Kibana view:
[image]

**Is there any way to disable serialization of results in Celery?**

I could add a pull-request with unpacking JSON, just for Elasticsearch, but it looks like a hack.

Answer (score 0):

Since v4.0 the default `result_serializer` is `json`, so you should have results in JSON format anyway. Maybe your configuration uses something else? - In that case I suggest you remove it (if you use Celery >=4.0) and you should enjoy results in JSON format. I prefer msgpack but on the other hand I do not use ElasticSearch on Celery results...

Comment: I've just installed Celery (4.3.0) and didn't change any configs. Mapping was created automatically. The only issue I can see is in the celery code for elasticsearch in the `_index` [function](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/_modules/celery/backends/elasticsearch.html#ElasticsearchBackend.mget) that result is converted to the dictionary, but not converted to JSON later, therefore elasticsearch thinks it is just a text. Currently the only solution I can see is to fork celery and add a line `json.dumps({bytes_to_str(k): v for k, v in items(body)})`, but it's not the best solution.

Comment: Did you try to explicitly set the serialisation format to JSON?

Comment: Celery docs are pretty confusing, I've tried to add every mention of json
`app = Celery(backend='elasticsearch://..., accept_content=['json'], result_accept_content = ['json'], serializer='json')`
Result is still text

Comment: Did you specify the result_serializer ?

Comment: Just added `result_serializer = 'json'` as well. It doesn't work anyway.